# How to use an ArcGIS Server cache directory with multiple (differently named) map services?

Tags: arcgis-server, arccatalog, map-service, cache

We have a map service named 'X' that created and uses tiles in a cache directory 'Folder_X'.

I'd like to create a second map service named 'Y' that uses the same cache directory - that is, it serves up the same tiles by a different service name.

So far, I see that when creating a service in ArcCatalog, it insists on using a cache directory named to match the service name, which of course isn't what I want. I see that there is a 'Folder_X'.cfg text file in the ...ArcGIS\server\user\cfg\Folder directory that I can edit to point to a different folder, but it seems to keep getting overwritten with the default value.

Ideas?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Server are you using for this?

Comment: Did you ever figured out how to do that?

Comment: Why do you have two services with exactly the same data?  I have managed to do this with two servers but the same service names - but never with different service names.  As noted below just up the number of instances on the one service.

Answer (score 1):

how about a virtual path definition for the map services cache?  I think it would require some crazy intervention using IIS, .net, and possible Apache modifications at version 10.1.
I would try increasing the instances available for the map service and try to utilize the same rest/soap endpoints in the application you are consuming these services from.  I am not clear on the purpose of having two services, so excuse me for blanketly redirecting the solution.